# How to enable CSRF protection in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

There is AntiXsrf code in ServiceStack, but it's not clear how to use it or enable it. Looking at network requests using chrome devtools, it doesn't appear to be turned on by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Razor page you can embed the token in your Form with:

```
<form action="/antiforgery/test" method="POST">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input name="Field" value="Test"/>        
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Which you can then validate in your Service with:

```
[Route("/antiforgery/test")]
public class AntiForgeryTest
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}

public class AntiForgeryService : Service
{
    public object Any(AntiForgeryTest request)
    {
        AntiForgery.Validate();
       ...
    }
}
```